# Shall I further belive DHARMapackages whan dignosed?

Tags: glmm

Today , I get the terrible resulits from the glmer.nb().  I tried a plent of methods to change the variables. However, When I finaly fitted a model with FUll variable . qqPlot(resid(Model)) tell me I got the right things but DHARMa's result told me I'm wrong. Shall I believe DHARMa Pakacages? Of course , I should appreciate the author for his contribution to DHARMa which is plenty easier to validate model, but today's result makes me confused.
These are the prodecures that I cope with my dataset:
1.`rm(M)`  #first I want to remove the case in case of unneccesary troublesome.

2.`M = glmer.nb(z ~ x + y + RC1 + RC2 + (1 | SITE) + 
    (1 | PID) + (1 | YEAR) + (1 | DATE), data = dt, verbose=TRUE,glmerControl(optimizer = c('bobyqa')))`
3.`simulateResiduals(M,n = 1000) %>% plot()`
  and DHARMa tells me how   terrible things are, like this!: 
[image]

4.but if I use qqPlot , it tells me like this, I think my model is ok, right? But DHARMa told me not. I don't know how to believe . Anybody could make a good interprete?

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
qqPlot(resid(M))
plot(resid(M) ~ fitted(M)); abline(h=0)
```

[image]

> And pardon me I can't upload my dataset for your convinience because it will exceed the number of character. If you know how to deal with it , please tell me . Thank you very much.

Comment: You can share a link to your dataset ...

Comment: can you give me anwser about the validation abouve?